# Gauge/getgauge: pass custom command line argument

Tags: command-line, arguments, gauge, getgauge

Does anybody know how I can run gauge with a custom argument to command line and handle it in python plugin?

For example:
When I launch gauge, I want also pass additional argument/flag to command line (> gauge run specs 17) and then handle it and use in my python code before/or when suites starts

Comment: Hi @Holiday, could you please post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was found.
I just added session enviroment variable.
https://github.com/getgauge/docs.gauge.org/blob/master/configuration.rst

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property to `env/default/default.properties` and use that property as an argument. 
E.g. `gauge run --env ci specs`
Reference: https://docs.gauge.org/latest/configuration.html#id1